# Filtering Dataframe column that is of Vector type in Apache Spark 2.1

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I am working on an outlier detection problem in Apache Spark and basically my approach of finding outliers is using a clustering method (k-means) to cluster my dataset and then classify those clusters with exactly one data point as anomalous. This is my first approach and so far it has been working so far.

Anyways, to make this work, I need to filter the features column (which is of vector type) and select the one whose value equals any of the cluster centers Vector array returned by the KMeansModel. However, when I try to do that, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector [1326.5,108633.25]
```

This is the code involving the filtering:

```
Dataset<Row> day1 = spark.read().
            option("header", "true").
            option("delimiter", "\t").
            option("inferSchema", "true").
            csv(day1txt);

VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler()
                    .setInputCols(new String[]{"Size", "Records"})
                    .setOutputCol("features");

Dataset<Row> day1vector = assembler.transform(day1);

BisectingKMeans kmeans = new BisectingKMeans().setSeed(1l);

BisectingKMeansModel model = kmeans.fit(day1vector);

Vector[] v = model.clusterCenters();

//I assume v[1] is anomalous in this case

day1vector.filter(day1vector.col("features").equalTo(v[1])).show(); //this provokes the error
```

Any idea of I can solve and go around this problem?